# Select an input type in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn Javascript selectors. How can I select an input type in JS?

```html
<div id="wrapper">

<input type="text" value="OFF" readonly/>

<button type="button">Click Me</button>

</div>
```

```js
const buttonElem = document.querySelector('button[type=button]');
const inputElem =  document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
buttonElem.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const oldText = inputElem.value;
    return inputElem.value = oldText === "ON" ? "OFF" : "ON";
});
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a list, if you want only one item use `querySelector`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I replaced it with just querySelector. it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You don't have any elements that match `input[type=button]`; you have `button[type=button]`.

Comment: Next: I think `return inputElem.value = oldText === "ON" ? "OFF" : "ON";` might work, but what is the point of returning the result of the assignment (which I believe it undefined)?

Comment: It still throws me an error.

Comment: Okay; what's that error say?

Comment: @Roh The code you have provided works fine as-is (https://jsfiddle.net/fot3w8Ls/). Please provide a [mre].

Comment: It Worked. Thanks for everyone helping. i just had Typo.